# mysql order by multiple conditions

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

I have sql in below, that want to make multiple ORDER BY.

```
SELECT
    r.*,
    s.uzunluq,
    b.id,
    au.status_id as aksessuar_status,
    au.aksessuar_id,
    au.aksessuar
FROM
    seksiya s,
    result r
LEFT JOIN bosh_seksiya_aksessuar b
    ON
    b.bosh_seksiya = r.model AND
    b.ERK = :ses
LEFT JOIN aksessuar_up au
    ON au.model_id = r.res_id AND
    au.user_id = :user_id AND
    au.status_id = 9
WHERE 
    r.user_id = :user_id AND
    r.model=s.seksiya AND 
    s.erk = :ses AND
    r.status_id IN (1,2,3,4,5)
ORDER BY 
    r.res_id
```

I think to write php PDO is not important for you, guys, cause my question only about with this sql. This sql works very good, I just want to add extra function. So, look to this column: `r.status_id IN (1,2,3,4,5)`

I have given `Order BY r.res_id`

MY question:
I want to use multiple ORDER for each `status_id`

HOW to order:

`ORDER BY r.res_id DESC WHERE r.status_id IN (1,2)`

AND

`ORDER BY r.res_id WHERE r.status_id IN (3,4,5)`

in this sql?

Comment: Maybe you would be better doing a `UNION`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```sql
ORDER BY IF(r.status_id IN (1,2), r.res_id, NULL) DESC, r.res_id
```

A recordset sorted with this `ORDER BY` clause will first display all records with `r.status_id IN (1,2)` (since `NULL` values come last in a descending ordering), themselves sorted in descending order of `r.res_id`; followed by all other values sorted by `r.res_id` in ascending order.

Comment: Tq. finally found the solution.

Answer (score 2):

you can use union syntax:

```
SELECT * FROM ((SELECT
    r.*,
    s.uzunluq,
    b.id,
    au.status_id as aksessuar_status,
    au.aksessuar_id,
    au.aksessuar,
    1 as query_order
FROM
    seksiya s,
    result r
LEFT JOIN bosh_seksiya_aksessuar b
    ON
    b.bosh_seksiya = r.model AND
    b.ERK = :ses
LEFT JOIN aksessuar_up au
    ON au.model_id = r.res_id AND
    au.user_id = :user_id AND
    au.status_id = 9
WHERE 
    r.user_id = :user_id AND
    r.model=s.seksiya AND 
    s.erk = :ses AND
    r.status_id IN (1,2)
ORDER BY 
    r.res_id DESC) as table1
UNION
(SELECT
    r.*,
    s.uzunluq,
    b.id,
    au.status_id as aksessuar_status,
    au.aksessuar_id,
    au.aksessuar,
    0 as query_order
FROM
    seksiya s,
    result r
LEFT JOIN bosh_seksiya_aksessuar b
    ON
    b.bosh_seksiya = r.model AND
    b.ERK = :ses
LEFT JOIN aksessuar_up au
    ON au.model_id = r.res_id AND
    au.user_id = :user_id AND
    au.status_id = 9
WHERE 
    r.user_id = :user_id AND
    r.model=s.seksiya AND 
    s.erk = :ses AND
    r.status_id IN (3,4,5)
ORDER BY 
    r.res_id) as table2) sa table3 ORDER BY query_order
```

Comment: OP wanted one as DESC an the other as default in order

Comment: Beware that one cannot use placeholder names multiple times in PDO, so one half of the `UNION` will need to use alternative names (to which variables will also need to be bound).

Comment: -1 Also beware that `UNION` does not *guarantee* that its result will preserve the order of its constituent queries or even the records within them.  To be certain of obtaining sorted results, you must add an additional column to signify from which query the record originated and use that in a further sort on the combined queries.

Comment: @eggyal added an order column in unions to sort unified resultset.

Comment: Aye, but you'd also need to sort the outer query by the appropriate direction of `r.res_id` - so perhaps this whole `UNION` thing has just got you back to where you started?  I'm not sure.